# Javascript queryselector doesn't work on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

please someone help me I've created a .js file for my simple website portfolio but in-state qualification if I click the button doesn't work. Does anyone know why ?

[image]

in the picture, if I click 'Work' it's won't change and still in education state.

```js
    const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(['data-target']),
      tabContents = document.querySelectorAll(['data-content'])

tabs.forEach(tab =>{
    tab.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        const target = document.querySelector(tab.dataset.target)
        
        tabContents.forEach(tabContent =>{
            tabContent.classList.remove('qualification__active')
        })
        target.classList.add('qualification__active')

        tabs.forEach(tab =>{
            tab.classList.remove('qualification__active')
        })
        tab.classList.add('qualification__active')
    })
})
```

```html
<div class="qualification__container container">
            <div class="qualification__tabs">
                <div class="qualification__button button--flex qualification__active" data-target='#education'>
                    <i class="uil uil-graduation-cap qualification__icon"></i>
                    Education
                </div>

                <div class="qualification__button button--flex" data-target="#work">
                    <i class="uil uil-briefcase-alt qualification__icon"></i>
                    Work
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I'am very new and I little bit confuse about to solve that, any advice on how to solve it?

Comment: The brackets for the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) need to be part of the string (so inside of the quotes). Otherwise you're passing an array as an argument.

Comment: Also I suggest delegation: `document.querySelector('.qualification__tabs').addEventListener('click', (e) => { const tgt = e.target.closest('div');`

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for `querySelectorAll` is wrong:

> ```
> const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(['data-target']),
>       tabContents = document.querySelectorAll(['data-content'])
> ```

It needs a string, but you are using an array.

Since you want to select by attribute the square brackets need to be part of the string:

```
 const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-target]'),
       tabContents = document.querySelectorAll('[data-content]')
```

Comment: @FabianS. Votes don't merely imply rightness. They represent "usefulness". I'm assuming it is downvoted because it answered a question that is caused by a typographical error. Those questions should be closed instead of answered, because they are very unlikely to help future visitors (which is what Stack Overflow is all about).

Comment: Well that actually makes sense @Ivar. Thanks for the clarification.